# Creating an arrayOf from multiple variables on the same line

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to learn Kotlin from Python and I need some help with how to create an array of different types using scanner class but keep getting an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Thanks in advance.

```kotlin
fun main(){

    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    println("Enter your name: ")
    println("Enter your height in inches: ")
    println("Enter your weight: ")
    val (name, height, weight) = arrayOf(scanner)
    println("your name is $name, your height is: $height your weight is $weight")

}
```

Comment: Are you struggling with having different types? Or creating an array with the users inputs? Because `arrayOf(scanner)` is just an array with your single scanner instance.

Comment: The issue i'm having is creating the array with multiple values. Should I be using a for loop for each value instead of val (name, height, weight)? I can convert the types later in my program. All i'm trying to do for now is create the array, or does it need to be a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in Kotlin, as well in Java, it is a bit different to get the input from the scanner, so try this:

```
val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    println("Enter your name: ")
    println("Enter your height in inches: ")
    println("Enter your weight: ")

    val (name, height, weight) = arrayOf(reader.next(), reader.nextInt(), reader.nextInt())
    println("your name is $name, your height is: $height your weight is $weight")
```

So if you wanted to wait for the inputs, you need to declare variables after `print()` or `println()` and init it to `scanner.next()` functions, then at the end you create your array in a single line using the variables.